# How to use a data object other than items in Dojo's ItemFileReadStore?

Tags: json, dojo

I am learning how to work with webservices using Dojo. The following JSON is returned from a webservice. I would like to handle it via an ItemFileReadStore, but from what I have tried so far the ItemFileReadStore only works if the keywordstat term is changed to items. Is there a way to tell ItemFileReadStore to work with keywordstat, or does it have to be items? It seems the other alternative is to write a custom store but that seems like overkill when ItemFileReadStore is so close.

```
{
  "keywordstat": [{
      "word": "Apple",
      "count": "1"
    }, "word": "It's", "count": "1"
  },
  {
    "word": "The",
    "count": "3"
  },
  {
    "word": "We've",
    "count": "1"
  },
  {
    "word": "amazing",
    "count": "1"
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out its absurdly simple to make a new ReadStore. I created a KeywordStatReadStore by copying the existing ItemFileReadStore and changing

```
    this._arrayOfTopLevelItems = dataObject.items;
```

to

```
    this._arrayOfTopLevelItems = dataObject.keywordstat;
```

Problem solved.

Comment: the alternative would be to do a simple transform (copy, actually) on your JSON data before feeding it to the store, such as a simple assignment statement myjson.items=myjson.keywordstat  You could probably subclass ItemFileReadStore rather than copy to make a change and avoid forking the code, but the assignment is a lot lighter.